# Cycles Nodes - object location in another object's space?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transforms

- The Object Info node gives me access to the location of the shaded object('s origin) in
  World Space
- The Texture Coordinate node gives me access to the coordinates of the shading point in the Object Space of any object.

How in a shader tree, could I retrieve the location of the shaded object in another object's space? For instance, the location of the shaded object in its parent's space?

Somehow apply the parent's inverse transform to the Object Info > Location?

Comment: Subtracting *Combine XYZ* (drived with parent world coordinates) from *Object Info* - is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @Serge L That is a partial solution, yes, as long as you can be sure that only translations are involved? Maybe the best that can be reached conveniently. It just seems odd to me that location isn't available in other bases.. you could do it in OSL, I think, if Cycles had it fully hooked up.. you could get to the transformation matrices of named objects.. but I don't _think_ it's there, in the Cycles implementation.

Comment: @Serge L maybe rotations are all that screw it.. by taking the transformed 0,0,0 and 1,1,1 you could deal with translation and scale...

Comment: Too bad, it is currently not implemented.  You can track it here : https://developer.blender.org/T52154 .   Related question : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81793/location-of-object-in-osl

Comment: @cppBeginner Thanks for bringing me back to this question! I'd forgotten it. Not in OSL.. it doesn't provide the space of a named object? But ordinary shader nodes can do it.. see answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was being dim.. to return the location of object A in the space of object B, in all A's shading points:

[image]

Here, 'A' is the shaded object, 'B' is an Empty.

Comment: Wow.  Thank for sharing.  Do you know any other nodes that receive `Object` as input besides "Texture Coordinate"? e.g. Is it possible to get the object name in string?

Comment: Don't think so, other than `self` ... there's Object Info  > Location, (which I could have used here) and Camera space is available via Camera Data, ( So, for example, you could tell where the camera is, without using drivers, the way many people do.. I think I've done that myself..)

Comment: Isn't this the same as `TextureCoordinate().Object + TextureCoordinate(Empty).Object`?

Comment: @ArtBIT   True! :D.. (with a flipped sign, but I see what you mean )  Addition and subtraction are associative, so it's the same as  `TextureCoordinate(Empty).Object - TextureCoordinate().Object`. I think when I answered I was going "kerchunk.. kerchunk" getting the positions and _then_ subtracting.  _Object Info_ > Location would do for the first chunk, too.  However, the whole thing fails under relative rotations, so nowadays a better way might be to use Geometry Nodes and feed the location out as an attribute?

Comment: Right, I forgot to negate the first arg. I guess I was also going "kerchunk... kerchunk" :P
Geo nodes are one way to do it, yeah, but sometimes you want to do it purely in shader nodes.